# Design pattern for child calling method in parent

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am currently working on my biggest project and I am having trouble figuring out how to structure my code.  I'm looking for some guidance.

I have 2 objects a **Tile** and **Container**.  Each **Tile** has a 2D coordinate and are all children of the **Container**.  The **Container** has methods that return tile for location, switch tiles, add tiles, and remove tiles.

Now when you click on a tile it disappears, that was easy because it was self contained.  The problem comes when I created different types of tiles that inherit from the base **Tile**.  Each different type of tile does a different action when you click on it.  Some destroy surrounding tiles some switch with other tiles and others add new tiles.  For simplicity we will call these 3 subclasses **Tile-destroy**, **Tile-swap**, and **Tile-add**.

My problem is when I click on these tiles how can they act on other tiles in the **Container**.  Should I just call functions in the parent class or is there a better way to do this?  I am having trouble #including the **Tile** in the **Container** as well as the other way around.  I feel like its not a proper pattern.

I have it set up so when a click takes place the **Container** handles it and checks the type of tile that is clicked and acts from there with a large else-if statement however this makes it very difficult to add new tile types.  Ideally all the information for what happens when you click on a tile is contained within each tile subclass.

Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on your language, your Container could have package protected methods accessible by tiles only (which resides in the same package). The container would then only delegate events to tiles and tiles would hold a reference to their container allowing manipulating other tiles. You would have two ways to remove a tile. One that simply removes the tile and one that delegate the removal operation to the tile. Therefore, if a tile destroys all it's neighbors and one of the destroyed tile should destroy it's right neighbor it would all happen,

Comment: except if the first destroyed tile overrides the sibling tiles destruction. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I am using Objective-C.  I am trying to read more about delegation package-protected methods are not possible.  Are you saying the method for destructing surrounding tiles would be in the tile and pass it off to the container?  I'm sorry but I am a little confused still.

Comment: Yes, the container provides fine grained methods for destroying tiles, adding tiles, etc, but those are meant to be called from tiles directly. E.g. of tile destroying sibling tiles when clicked... `user clicks on tile -> container.handleClick(tilePosition) -> tile.handleClick() -> container.destroySiblingsOf(this)` It could be different but that's the essence of double dispatching.

Comment: You will also want to control if the destroyed siblings should also kick of their destroying logic or not. That could be different methods e.g. `destroySiblingOfWithoutPropagation vs destroySiblingsOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you the simpliest design:

1. Your Container will be a game controller
2. Each tile has Parent property which is refer to Container
3. When you click on tile it sends Command to Container (for example, DestroyTile(x, y) or AddTile(x, y)
4. Container handle this commands and destroys, adds or swap tiles.

If you want really good and more decoupled design you can also create handlers for all operation types DestroyTileHandler, AddTileHandler. In Container on different commands you will just pass them [commands] to appropriate handler. Also you need to pass context object (like Field with tiles) to handler. This allows you to add and modify new operations without even changing Container code.

See related patterns: Command, Observer

Feel free to ask questions and good luck!